# 'java.util.ArrayList' cannot be applied to '(<lambda parameter>)'

Tags: java, android

How can I fix this problem?

```
rv_groupAddMember.setAdapter(new GroupAdapter(groupModelList, position -> {
                selectedGroup = groupModelList.get(position);
                addMember_groupName.setText("Seçili Grup :"+selectedGroup.getGroupName());
            }));
```

```
public class GroupAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GroupAdapter.GroupViewHolder>{
List<GroupModel> groupModelList;
OnClickItem onClickItem;

public GroupAdapter(List<GroupModel> groupModelList, OnClickItem onClickItem) {
    this.groupModelList = groupModelList;
    this.onClickItem = onClickItem;
}
```

I added my GroupAdapter class and constructor
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95QMA.jpg)

I'm watching tutorial everything is the same and there shouldn't be an error.

Comment: Can you provide more information? And also: Don't post images of errors..

Comment: Post `GroupAdapter` class, but it looks like it doesn't allow lambdas as you are passing as second parameter.

Comment: required: List<GroupModel>
  found: ArrayList<GroupModel>,(position)[...])); }
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't add information in the comments.

Comment: What is `OnClickItem`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, java needs to figure out what the lambda is actually trying to be, and *only then* can it know what the type of `position` is. For example, given:

```
void foo(Consumer<String> x) { ... }
```

If you then write: `foo(s -> System.out.println(s));` - java knows that the type of `s` is `String` only because of this sequence of events:

- There is only one `foo` method.
- That method takes a param of type `Consumer<String>`.
- That type is a functional interface (an interface with a single method), and that method's signature is `void accept(String t)`.
- The lambda is an implementation of that method, therefore, `s` must be `String`.

And only then can java continue to actually understand what the lambda contains.

Your error is telling you in a somewhat odd way that the compiler is not currently capable of figuring out what the functional interface is that this lambda is implementing. Therefore, it does not know what the type of `position` is, therefore, the call `groupModelList.get(position)` does not work; `int` is required, but the type of `position` is 'I do not know yet; I cannot know until I know what functional interface this lambda is trying to implementation and for some reason I can't know that right now'. Which isn't `int`, so you get that error.

one trivial fix is to be explicit. Make that `(int position) -> { ... }` instead. This may then lead you to the real error you're interested in. For example, if you haven't imported `GroupAdapter`, this would happen.